# Why doesn't my hopper deposit items in the box?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've decided to replace the piston-powered "item slider" on the bottom of the mob grinder with a hopper attached to a chest. A similar setup elsewhere works fine, but here - the hopper accepts the items but doesn't deposit them in the chest. The chest can open just fine, and in effect I have no clue what's wrong that the hopper doesn't deposit its items.

[image: right side]
[image: left side]
[image: from below]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To me, it looks like the hopper is trying to deposit the items into the stone slabs next to it, rather than the chest.

If you place the chest, then hold shift and right-click the chest while holding the hopper the hopper should "snap" to the chest, like in my picture below on the left (ignore the gap).
[image]

If I put stuff in the hopper on the left, the items get pulled through to the chest.
[image]

The one on the right is what I think is happening to yours, the hopper is linked to the wall and isn't passing items to the chest.

Comment: I was stuck at "How do I attach the hopper to a chest, if right-click opens it..."

Comment: @SF. that's why you need to hold shift.

Comment: the sneak right click activates the item in your hand over the block, non-sneak activates the block over the item

Comment: Shift right click to put hoppers on top of chests? I missed that one. I've been putting the hopper on top of a block then replacing the block with a chest. That is so much easier!

Answer (score -3):

This applies if your playing multiplayer on a bukkit server

also the lockette plugin disables hoppers when the chest is locked

do /cremove on the chest and make sure its in a room with a locked door and protected from greif. so noone can steal from the chest

Comment: This question is about vanilla hoppers and chests, not any features found in mods.

Comment: @MBraedley Still might be very useful for others in the same situation.